# .htaccess -Запретить доступ к директории и ее файлам для всех, кроме одного домена

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, как настроить .htaccess.

Есть несколько доменов, которые прикреплены к одной директории на сервере:

site1.ru

site2.ru

...

siteN.ru

прикреплены к ---> /home/user/web/mysite/public_html/

Внутри этот папки есть директория notpublic, в которой хранятся директории и файлы:

/home/user/web/mysite/public_html/notpublic/

Необходимо запретить доступ к этой директории и всем ее поддиректорими и файлам для всех сайтов, кроме site1.ru таким образом, чтобы на любой запрос с этих доменов сервер возвращал бы ошибку 404:

http://site2.ru/notpublic/1.jpg ---> error 404

http://site3.ru/notpublic/* ---> error 404

и т.д. 
Чтобы из вне казалось, что нет на сервере этой директории и ее содержимого.

А вот для домена site1.ru:

http://site1.ru/notpublic/1.jpg ---> 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

В каталог `notpublic` поместите такой `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site1\.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает только при отключенном ngix.

Comment: Можно ли заставить описанный способ работать, при включенном ngix?

Comment: Можно. Настроить nginx. Скиньте свой конфиг в текст исходного вопроса. ИЛИ отдавать статику не nginx напрямую. Опять же, конфиг в студию